# Images don't open using Image.open(fnames) and code have " 'list' object has no attribute 'read' " error

Tags: python-3.x, image, subdirectory

I have some subfolders(s1,s2,s3,...). I want to open images in the subfolders in the "Image" folder in path:
"E:/Image/" and show them. But images can not be opened.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
root = "E:/Image/" 
path = os.path.join(root,"")
for r in os.walk(path):
     for file in r:
        fnames = glob.glob(f'{root}{r}/{file}')
        img1 = Image.open(fnames)
        img1.show()
```

My code have this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2546     try:
-> 2547         fp.seek(0)
   2548     except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e9dafc96965e> in <module>()
      9         fnames = glob.glob(f'{root}{r}/{file}')
     10 
---> 11         img1 = Image.open(fnames)
     12        
     13         img1.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2547         fp.seek(0)
   2548     except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):
-> 2549         fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
   2550         exclusive_fp = True
   2551 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Please post also the traceback, so that we see what is the error. Also, I doubt that you have files called ``'{root}{file}/*.jpg'``; did you forget a "f" in front of the string?

Comment: I add "f" but there is still a problem.

Comment: again: which problem? Post the full traceback. "There is a problem" doesn't mean much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the exception because you pass a list to instead of a file name to `Image.open`.

However the main issues that I see are related to the wrong use of [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) and [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob).
I suggest to carefully read the documentation before using a functionality that you don't know.

A clarification:

- `os.walk` doesn't return the name of the files in `path` but, recursively, a directory (`dirpath`), the list of subdirectories (`dirnames`) and the list of the files in the directory (`filenames`). You can get all the file names simply doing `os.path.join(dirpath, name)` for each `name` in in `filenames`.
- `glob.glob` returns a list of files matching the given wildcards. From your code, I imagine that you expect that `f'{root}{r}/{file}'` is the name of a file on the system, so there is no need to complicate your life using `glob.glob`

A a couple of notes:

- since your `root` already has a trailing `/`, the call to `os.path.join(root,"")` does nothing;
- if you want to create file paths programmatically, do not add path separators by hand, but try to use `os.path.join` (or if necessary `os.sep`) as much as possible (it helps to maintain cross-system compatibility). As example instead of doing

  ```
  root = "E:/Image/" 
  r = 'folder'
  file = 'test.txt'
  fname = f'{root}{r}/{file}'
  ```

  use

  ```
  root = "E:/Image" 
  r = 'folder'
  file = 'test.txt'
  fname = os.path.join(root, r, file)
  ```

### The code

And now the "correct" code. Since I don't know your directory structure, user case and such, the code might now work as you want, but I hope that you can adapt it to your needs.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

root = "E:/Image/" 
for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
    # we don't care about ``dirnames``
    for name in filenames:
        fname = op.path.join(dirpath, name)
        img1 = Image.open(fname)
        img1.show()
```